Unable to resolve service for type 'WebAPI.Models.ZamanlaContext' while attempting to activate 'WebAPI.Controllers.StoryTellingController'
I'm encountering an issue with my ASP.NET Core Web API project. When trying to access data through the /api/StoryTelling endpoint, I'm getting the following error:
"Message": "Unable to resolve service for type 'WebAPI.Models.ZamanlaContext' while attempting to activate 'WebAPI.Controllers.StoryTellingController'.
Details:
In my Startup.cs file, I've configured the ZamanlaContext in the ConfigureServices method as follows:




public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var connectionString = _Configuration.GetConnectionString("ZamanlaDB");

    services.Configure<IISOptions>(options => { });
    
    services.AddDbContext<ZamanlaContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        options.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
    });
}




In my StoryTellingController.cs file, I have the following controller:




namespace WebAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class StoryTellingController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ZamanlaContext _context;

        public StoryTellingController(ZamanlaContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
    
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetAllApprovedStories()
        {
            var stories = _context.StoryTelling
                .Where(x => x.IsApproved)
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
                .ToList();
            return Ok(stories);
        }
    }
}




And here's my ZamanlaContext.cs file:




namespace WebAPI.Models
{
    public class ZamanlaContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
    {
        public ZamanlaContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Video> Video { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Customers> Customers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<StoryTelling> StoryTelling { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserRefreshToken> UserRefreshToken { get; set; }
        public DbSet<FAQ> FAQ { get; set; }
        public DbSet<NewsItems> NewsItems { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Blog> Blog { get; set; }
    }
}




The database connection is successful, but I'm unable to resolve the service for ZamanlaContext. What am I missing or doing wrong?
